# How to split colums into multiple colums and find frequency in R?

Tags: r, sorting, aggregation

**ODK response**

```
1
1; 2
1; 2; 3
1; 2; 3; 5
1; 2; 4
1; 2; 4; 5; 6
1; 2; 4; 6
1; 2; 4; 7
```

---

```
1 is Crop failure-
2 is Water shortage
3 is Land degradation
4 is Lack of HH Labor
5 is Lack of income from agriculture
6 is Lack of manure / fertilizer
7 is Others
```

**I would like to get a table like this**

```
Crop failure- 8
Water shortage- 7
Land degradation- 6
Lack of HH Labor- 1
Lack of income from agriculture- 2
Lack of manure / fertilizer- 2
Others- 1
```

I have tried in 'Split single column with multiple values into multiple colums' using dplyr in R but couldn't please help.

Comment: Why `Land degradation- 6 Lack of HH Labor- 1`? It should be 2 and 4, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my swing at the problem. I use tidyverse because it loads stringr and tidyr in for me

```
library(tidyverse)

id <- data.frame(Code = 1:7, #Make a coding data frame so you can label the results
                 Cause = c("Crop failure", "Water shortage", "Land degradation", "Lack of HH Labor", "Lack of income from agriculture", "Lack of manure / fertilizer", "Others"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

data <- Book1 %>% 
  separate(X1, into = paste0("X", 1:7), sep = ";") %>% #split the data by the ;, This induces NA that are removed later
  gather(key = "drop", value = "Code") %>% #put it into 1 column to exploit R's vectorization
  mutate(Code = as.integer(Code)) %>% #Make the code an integer for the join later
  filter(!is.na(Code)) %>% #remove those previous NAs
  group_by(Code) %>% 
  count() %>% # Counts 
  left_join(., id) #labels

colnames(data) <- c("Code", "Count", "Cause")
```

It will throw a warning at the separate line but, it is just letting you know it is filling the extra cells with NA which we remove later. The only things you might have to change are DataFrame and X1, depending on what you named your objects.

Here is what my results look like

```
 Code Count Cause                          
  <int> <int> <chr>                          
1     1     8 Crop failure                   
2     2     7 Water shortage                 
3     3     2 Land degradation               
4     4     4 Lack of HH Labor               
5     5     2 Lack of income from agriculture
6     6     2 Lack of manure / fertilizer    
7     7     1 Others
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1):

- If you would like to use `base R`, the following solution may help you.

Assuming your input is

```
response <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 7)
```

then

```
status <- c("Crop failure", "Water shortage", "Lang degradation", "Lack of HH Labor",  "Lack of income from agriculture", "Lack of manure / fertilizer", "Others")
df <- as.data.frame(table(factor(response,labels = status),dnn = list("Status")))
```

can give you the output like

```
> df
                           Status Freq
1                    Crop failure    8
2                  Water shortage    7
3                Lang degradation    2
4                Lack of HH Labor    4
5 Lack of income from agriculture    2
6     Lack of manure / fertilizer    2
7                          Others    1
```

- If you want to have a detailed table:
  Assuming your input is:

```
r <- list(1, c(1, 2), c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3, 5), c(1, 2, 4), c(1, 
2, 4, 5, 6), c(1, 2, 4), 6, c(1, 2, 4, 7))
```

```
type = seq(1,7)
dt <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(r, function(v) sapply(type, function(k) sum(k==v)))))
colnames(M) <- paste0("type",type)
```

which gives

```
> dt
  type1 type2 type3 type4 type5 type6 type7
1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
2     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
3     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
4     1     1     1     0     1     0     0
5     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
6     1     1     0     1     1     1     0
7     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
8     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
9     1     1     0     1     0     0     1
```

Besides, the sum of each type entries can be calculated by `colSums`:

```
> colSums(dt)
type1 type2 type3 type4 type5 type6 type7 
    8     7     2     4     2     2     1
```

Or you can use `match()`, i.e.,

```
dt <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(r, function(v) !is.na(match(type,v)))))
> dt
  type1 type2 type3 type4 type5 type6 type7
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
7  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
9  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: My data is stored in a .csv file. 
1; 2
1; 2; 3
1; 2; 3; 5
1; 2; 4
1; 2; 4; 5; 6
1; 2; 4; 6
1; 2; 4; 7
1; 2; 5
1; 2; 5; 6
1; 2; 5; 7
1; 2; 6
1; 2; 7
1; 3
1; 3; 7
1; 4
1; 5
1; 5; 6
1; 6
2
2; 3
2; 3; 5
2; 3; 6
2; 4; 6
2; 5
2; 5; 6
2; 5; 7
2; 6
2; 7
5
5; 7
7 would like to count and get a sum of all the 1 (Crop failure), 2 (Water shortage), 3 (Lang degradation), etc. as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read the numbers from .csv file? or what do you want? @SaneeshCS I suggest you provide some toy examples in code or picture in your question post, which would be easier for others to help you

Comment: I want to count variables of multiple rows in a column and get sum of all the 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Your rows are separated by `;`? @SaneeshCS

Comment: There are multiple variables in a single cell e.g- cell one has only 1 and cell two has 1;2, cell 3 has 1;2;3, etc. All the variables in a single cell are separated by ;

Comment: See my second solution, but no idea if you want this format@SaneeshCS

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f3PHq54uukXB8Bm0ddGDiP-2ZAN6OPL3/view?usp=sharing one set of data is here with a sheet with expected output.

Comment: My first solution is in the format of your expected output, what do you think? @SaneeshCS

Answer (score 0):

Using `plyr`, you can obtain the following:

```r
Condition = c("Crop failure", "Water shortage", "Lang degradation", "Lack of HH Labor",  "Lack of income from agriculture", "Lack of manure / fertilizer", "Others")
Type = c(1:7)
df = data.frame(Condition, Type)

vector = c(1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,5,1,2,4,1,2,4,5,6,1,2,4,6,1,2,4,7)
t = plyr::count(vector)
colnames(t) = c("Type","Freq")

df =merge(df,t)
```

And you get:

```r
> df
  Type                       Condition Freq
1    1                    Crop failure    8
2    2                  Water shortage    7
3    3                Lang degradation    2
4    4                Lack of HH Labor    4
5    5 Lack of income from agriculture    2
6    6     Lack of manure / fertilizer    2
7    7                          Others    1
```

Comment: There are multiple variables in a single cell e.g- cell one has only 1 and cell two has 1;2, cell 3 has 1;2;3, etc. All the variables in a single cell are separated by ; In the .csv file there are 32 such rows in a single column with multiple values. My attempt is to get sum of all the 1,2, 3, etc.